# How to show a picture using GDI?

Tags: c

it is possible to display a picture on a window created by winmain i mean using GDI,

i want do create a window that captures my whole screen i have done that by using GDI but unable to show an image on it how can i do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [lots](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html) of [good](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/views/DisplayBitmap.htm) [tutorials](http://www.ucosoft.com/how-to-draw-bitmap-from-a-bmp-file.html) on the [web](http://www.google.com/search?q=draw+bitmap+win32).